# How to add different values of the same field

Tags: python, django

Raw has the process field (1/0) when adding the **process=1**, it does well but when adding the **process=0**; it brings me the same value of `process=1`.

Out

```
category | totalProcess | totalNoProcess
A        | 100          | 100
```

Desired result

```
category | totalProcess | totalNoProcess
A        | 100          | 0
```

query in mysql:

`SELECT download, SUM(CASE WHEN process = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Processed, SUM(CASE WHEN process = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoPreoces FROM oer_raw where download=1;`

use `annote`, `count`, `case` is:

```py
metaData = Raw.objects.values('download__category_name').annotate(
        totalProcess = Count(Case(When(process=1, then=Value(1)), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField())),
        totalNoProcess = Count(Case(When(process=0, then=Value(1)), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()))
        ).get(download = disciplina.id)
```

the relationship between Download and Raw is 1 - *

so that the **FK** is in Raw with the name of download, that's why I use `get` to obtain the sum of what the FK I am looking for has

Comment: Exactly how does the data in the database looks like?

Comment: You need to use Sum not Count

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem something like this `raw (1, "FK 2", 0, "field 4")`

Comment: @IainShelvington now I check the `sum`

Comment: @Cristian and? Is it working now?

Comment: @IainShelvington if that was carelessness myself (in that case I have to check the difference between `count `and `sum`

Answer (score 1):

`Count` will count all non-NULL values, so you either should use as default `None`/`Null`:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, Q, Value, When, IntegerField

metaData = Raw.objects.values('download__category_name').annotate(
    totalProcess = Count(Case(
        When(process=1, then=Value(1)),
        default=None,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )),
    totalProcess = Count(Case(
        When(~Q(process=1), then=Value(1)),
        default=None,
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
).get(download=disciplina.id)
```

But actually since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you don't need to filter this that way. You can simply use the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter):

```
# since Django-2.0

from django.db.models import Count, Q

metaData = Raw.objects.values('download__category_name').annotate(
    totalProcess = Count('pk', filter=Q(process=1)),
    totalProcess = Count('pk', filter=~Q(process=1))
).get(download=disciplina.id)
```

If `process` can only be `0` and `1`, you can even reduce this to:

```
# process is only 0/1

from django.db.models import Count, Sum

metaData = Raw.objects.values('download__category_name').annotate(
    totalProcess = Sum('process'),
    totalProcess = Count('pk')-Sum('process'),
).get(download=disciplina.id)
```